# Why does the expression $3n+1$ appear in Collatz conjecture?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

Why is it important the role of $3n+1$ in Collatz conjecture? I mean, if we replace $3n+1$ by $5n+1$ it seems (numerically) that the modified statement of Collatz conjecture does not hold in this case.

So I assume that putting $3n+1$ is special in some sense, but which is the idea behind it? Are there any informal ideas that can make us think that the long time behaviour with $3n+1$ should be distinct than with $5n+1$, $7n+1$,...

Does anybody know what happens when we change $3$ by another odd number (proof or at least some kind of intuition)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Related: [How could Collatz conjecture possibly be undecidable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156004/how-could-collatz-conjecture-possibly-be-undecidable)  Mention is made there (by an Answer) of one type of generalized Collatz problem.

Comment: The extensive survey [by J. Lagarias](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf) includes information about generalized Collatz problems.  Item 43 in particular concerns the undecidability of some problems, established by J. Conway.

Comment: For a start you might look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78124/implication-for-m-cycles-in-collatz-type-problems  or this one https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177719/3n1-problem-and-cycles/200126#200126  (of course besides of wp and Lagarias...)

Comment: Thank you all. I'll look in detail to these references. I also found this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/470483/231756 which gives a good "first intuition".

Answer (score 5):

Replacing $3$ with a larger odd number makes numbers grow, on average. To see this, consider the $qx+1$ function, where $q$ is odd. An odd number grows by a factor of about $q$, after which it divides by $2$ some number of times. Half of the time, you get $1$ division step, one fourth of the time, you get $2$, one eighth of the time, you get $3$, etc.

Thus, the average size change from one odd number to the next one in its trajectory is:

$$\frac12\left(\frac{q}2\right)+\frac14\left(\frac{q}4\right)+\frac18\left(\frac{q}8\right)+\cdots,$$

which simplifies as a geometric series sum to $\dfrac{q}3$. If $q>3$, this quantity is larger than $1$, which means that odd numbers will, on average, grow as a result of the action of this function. When $q=3$, the forces of growth and shrinking are basically balanced, on average, so you get interesting dynamics in their tug-of-war.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00908.pdf)?

Comment: @DaBler - I had not. Thank you; that's very interesting indeed!

Answer (score 2):

This question ***"Why does(...)"*** can only be answered by Collatz himself or by research in his mathematical notes.
Let's see what Lagaraias (in his overview)$\;^{(1)}$ has to say:

> ### 2. History and Background
>
> The 3x+1 problem circulated by word of mouth for many years. It is generally
>   attributed to Lothar Collatz. He has stated ([14]) that he took lecture courses in
>   1929 with Edmund Landau and Fritz von Lettenmeyer in G¨ottingen, and courses
>   in 1930 with Oskar Perron in Munich and with Issai Schur in Berlin, the latter
>   course including some graph theory. **He was interested in graphical representations
>   of iteration of functions.** In his notebooks in the 1930’s he formulated questions on
>   iteration of arithmetic functions of a similar kind (cf. [58, p.3]). Collatz is said
>   by others to have circulated the problem orally at the International Congress of
>   Mathematicians in Cambridge, Mass. in 1950. Several people whose names were
>   subsequently associated with the problem gave invited talks at this International
>   Congress, including H. S. M. Coxeter, S. Kakutani, and S. Ulam.(...)

*(Enhancing by me)* It means, Collatz worked with various problems of this type, and specifically the version $3x+1$ he disseminated to collegues as being a difficult one.

This is just a short peeking into one reliable source, but by his references **"[14]"**, **"[58]"**  there should be answers with more detailed reasons possible here (I don'thave the book myself) ... *P.s. such an information should surely be made available in the wikipedia-entry, if it is not yet there (didn't check it)*

***update*** Here is a screenshot from Lagarias' 1985 survey which gives again a bit more background, but I'd say your question "why..." needs even more specific details in its answer...

[image: picture]

(from $\;^{(2)}$ )

---

$\;^{(1)}$ *Lagarias, Jeffrey C.*, [**The (3x+1) problem: an overview**](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-78-prev.pdf), Lagarias, Jeffrey C. (ed.), The ultimate challenge. The (3x+1) problem. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-4940-8/hbk). 3-29 (2010). [ZBL1253.11036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1253.11036).

$\;^{(2)}$ *Lagarias, Jeffrey C.*, [**The (3x+1) problem and its generalizations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2322189), Am. Math. Mon. 92, 3-23 (1985). [ZBL0566.10007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0566.10007).